# How can it be determined if one integer is divisble by another?

Tags: java

So for this problem the question asks

> a number x is divisible by y if the remainder after the division is zero. Write a program that tests whether one number is divisible by another number. read both numbers from the keyboard.

This is what I have so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ch3ProblemOne 
{

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

     int x;
     int y;
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     x = keyboard.nextInt();
     y = keyboard.nextInt();

     if (x == 5);
     else if (y <= 0);
     System.out.println(x + "is not divisible by" + y);

     else if (x == y);

     System.out.println(x + "is divisible by" + y);
```

Comment: And don't forget that integers are always rounded down. 5/2 = 2, not 2.5.

Comment: And you could use the fact that integer division truncates, as ben said, instead of using the modulus operator (%).  If 5/2 = 2, then 2*2=4, and 4 != 5 --> so 5 does not divide by 2.

Answer (score 10):

you need to use the modulus operator, which tells what the remainder is.

so

```
10 % 2 == 0

10 % 7 == 3
```

Use `%` on your variables.

Comment: But be sure not to mod by zero!

Comment: ... or deal with the ArithmeticException that results if you do divide by zero.  (I'm not going to say which approach is better.  The OP ultimately needs to understand how to deal with exceptions ... and when it is better to prevent them happening in the first place.  But these are "more advanced" topics.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) [operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html), which returns the remainder from a division operation.

```
public class ch3ProblemOne {

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     int x = keyboard.nextInt();
     int y = keyboard.nextInt();

     if ((x % y) == 0) { System.out.println(x + " is divisible by " + y); }
     else { System.out.println(x + " is not divisible by " + y); }
  }
}
```

Comment: Too much code for a homework answer.  Give hints, not potted answers.